# Erro DirectShow9 Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, embarcadero

Boa Tarde Galera!
Estou com um erro ao compilar meu projeto no Delhphi 7, quando compilo ele me da o seguinte erro Fatal

**[Fatal Error] AUTOINSTALADOR.dpr(6): Unit DirectShow9 was compiled with a different version of DirectDraw.IDirectDraw**

o que pode estar acontecendo? Ja coloquei o arquivo Directshow9 na pasta do projeto.

Comment: As versão está diferente da que está usando... Você atualizou o componente?

Comment: Não atualizei, irei ver isso agor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este erro fatal ocorre quando a declaração de símbolo declarada na parte de interface de uma unidade foi alterada e o compilador não consegue recompilar uma unidade que depende desta declaração porque a origem não está disponível para ele.

Existem várias soluções possíveis - recompilar Unit1 (supondo que você tenha o código-fonte disponível), use uma versão mais antiga da Unit2 ou altere Unit2 ou obtenha uma nova versão de Unit1 de quem tiver o código-fonte.

Este erro também pode ocorrer quando uma unidade em seu projeto tem o mesmo nome de uma unidade Delphi padrão.

Por exemplo, isso pode ocorrer ao compilar um projeto escrito em uma versão anterior do Delphi que não tenha uma unidade com este nome (por exemplo, search.pas não estava no Delphi 3).

Para resolver o problema neste caso:

Abra o  e salve-o com um novo nome.
Altere todas as referências a  em cláusulas uses para se referir ao novo nome.
Elimine as antigas versões  .pas e  .dcu desta unidade.
Recrie o projeto.

Retirado do: [http://docwiki.embarcadero.com](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Berlin/en/Code_Examples_by_Functionality)

Comment: +1 pela resposta correta, vale lembrar que este problema não poderá ser resolvi se não possuir o `.pas`.